# What is Barack Obama trying to say here in the highlighted sentence given down below from his book Dreams From My Father?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

Is he saying here that working is capitol building is not as good as working at the state legislative office ? Please make me understand. I couldn't make sense out of it.

**“because within the capitol building of a big, industrial state, one sees every day the face of a nation in constant conversation: inner-city mothers and corn and bean farmers, immigrant day laborers alongside suburban investment bankers—all jostling to be heard, all ready to tell their stories.”**

[image: d]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paragraph is comparing working in a state capitol building to working in Washington, the capital of the whole nation. Obama says that some think that state government is not as glamorous as national government, but that he found working at the state level satisfying. He mentions several reasons, such as concrete results in a shorter time frame than in national politics.

He then adds to those reasons in this sentence beginning with "And too,", mentioning all the individuals and groups that are there every day, interacting with each other ("in constant conversation"), and competing for attention ("jostling to be heard").

Answer (score 2):

Jack O’Flaherty’s explanation is correct. I would like to add that Former President Obama is specifically pointing out the vastness of diversity one faces in state politics vs national politics.

Politics on the federal level takes a bit of an elitist tone. It takes a lot of time, effort, grass-roots support, corporate (or corporate-style) backing, media coverage, and, of course, money to get an audience with political decision makers.

On the state and local level, both rich (suburban investment bankers) and poor (immigrant day laborers), rural (corn and bean farmers) and urban (inner-city mothers), can get their voice heard. And, even sometimes acknowledged.

Your constituents on a state level are as diverse as this nation. Yet, they have more direct access to their state government representatives. Each constituent also has more representation since the votes they cast to elect their representatives counts directly and with a higher percentage value per voter. Regardless of their status, your constituents can not be ignored.